# Include not working in classes?

Tags: php, pdo

I'm not sure if this is just me, but whenever i try to use the `include` method it fails.

```
<?php
  include_once 'db.php';
    class Cookies{
        public function Verify($Cookie){
            echo($dbh);
            $CookieStmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM Cookies WHERE Cookie=:cookie");
            $CookieStmt->bindParam(":cookie",$Cookie);
            $CookieStmtExe = $CookieStmt->execute();
            if($CookieRow=$CookieStmtExe->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                if($CookieRow['EndDate']>time()){
                    return true;
                }else{
                            return false;
                        }
                       } else{
                    return false;
                }

        }
}
        ?>
```

I've also tried `include` inside the function `Verify`but it would always echo out: Notice: Undefined variable: dbh on line 5

And yes I have defined `$dbh` in `db.php`

**UPDATE**: I even tried a direct connection and it's still failing

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=baheeg', 'root', '');
class Cookies{
    public function Verify($Cookie){
        echo($dbh);
        $CookieStmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM Cookies WHERE Cookie=:cookie");
        $CookieStmt->bindParam(":cookie",$Cookie);
        $CookieStmtExe = $CookieStmt->execute();
        if($CookieRow=$CookieStmtExe->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            if($CookieRow['EndDate']>time()){
                return true;
            }else{
                        return false;
                    }
                   } else{
                return false;
            }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is variable scope. Since you assign the variable `$dbh` outside the function, it's not available inside the function unless you use a `global` declaration.

```
<?php
include_once 'db.php';
class Cookies{
    public function Verify($Cookie){
        global $dbh;

        echo($dbh);
        $CookieStmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM Cookies WHERE Cookie=:cookie");
        $CookieStmt->bindParam(":cookie",$Cookie);
        $CookieStmtExe = $CookieStmt->execute();
        if($CookieRow=$CookieStmtExe->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            if($CookieRow['EndDate']>time()){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        } else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

You could also put the `include` statement inside the function, but then you must use `include`, not `include_once` because it will only be included in the first function that you call, and the others will skip it.